# vetamen ha is not a validate name (reserved java keywords)

Tags: android, xml

error : vetamen‌ha is not a validate name (reserved java keywords)

```
<string name="vetamen‌ha"> vetamen‌ha </string>
```

validate resource references inside android xml

How do I solve this problem?

update :

image : http://8pic.ir/images/5xkpf6dccdzs5o1spixd.jpg

Comment: what do you want to do with  this string.xml file? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why does this error occur?

Comment: Post the code where you try to access this string element

Comment: when this error occured? when you running your programe or does it gives popup error inside yiur xml file?

Comment: popup error inside xml file